# getting an error while rebuilding my Android Studio project

Tags: java, c++, c, android-studio

I am getting stuck because of this error and can't test my application.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give them a value like you gave to the rest of the dimension:

```
<dimen name= activity_horizontal_margin>**yourvalue**</dimen>
```

Replace **yourvalue** with values like the other ones in the file, and to the same for the rest of the dimensions that give this error :)

Answer (score 1):

You only can specific value in `dimen` tag. So, please give them a `sp` or `dp` value instead of name.

Hope this helped.